# Ansible way of replacing a line in config

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I have a json as follows:

```
{
    "bootstrap": true,
    "server": true,
    "datacenter": "aws",
    "data_dir": "/var/consul",
    "log_level": "INFO",
    "enable_syslog": true
}
```

This is on 3 servers which are in ansible inventory file as

```
[consul]
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3
```

Now to make the nodes join the cluster i will have to actually add the following config line as well

```
"start_join": ["ip_of_other_node_1", "ip_of_other_node_2"]
```

and this will go on each of the 3 servers

So basically it means if `10.0.0.1` is one of those nodes in cluster, it's config will look like

```
{
    "bootstrap": true,
    "server": true,
    "datacenter": "aws",
    "data_dir": "/var/consul",
    "log_level": "INFO",
    "enable_syslog": true,
    "start_join": ["10.0.0.2","10.0.0.3"]
}
```

I am trying to this via ansible as follows:

```
  - name: Add the ip's of other servers to join cluster
    lineinfile:
        path: /etc/consul.d/server/config.json
        regexp: '^"enable_syslog"'
        insertafter: '^"enable_syslog"'
        line: '"start_join": ["{{ groups['consul'][1] }}", "{{ groups['consul'][2] }}"]'
    when: inventory_hostname == '{{ groups['consul'][0] }}'
```

Which is not really helping me out saying syntax error at line: , i am not sure what is the best way to achieve something like this via ansible and also what how to tackle the case when i increase the servers in inventory.

Comment: The title suggests the question is about "*replacing a line in config*"; the body of the question shows 6 lines in the original file, and 7 in the expected file. Precisely which line gets replaced with what?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Template module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html) to replace the config file on your servers, instead of changing it in place with the regex. This way you can add a task to generate a new config file with the `start_join` field containing the elements of your hosts file (or any other and more complex configuration) using regular `jinja2` templates.